# UDF (DVD-R) incremental writing of changed file sectors

Tags: windows, backup, user-defined-functions, dvd

The UDF [file system specification](http://www.osta.org/specs/pdf/udf260.pdf) , specifically paragraph "2.2.11 Virtual Allocation Table" apparently allows writing incremental changes to the files.

I.e. let's say I have a large file of 1 GB size on my HDD, and I burned a backup copy of  it to a DVD-R. Then I made a small modification of the first 1 MB of that file on the HDD and I need to update the backup copy on the DVD-R disc. According to the above mentioned paragraph it should be possible to only write those changed 1 MB sectors using VAT, instead of copying and writing the entire 1 GB file again, thus saving a lot of space on the DVD.

However when I try that test with Windows it seems to write the entire file, i.e. the second copy occupies 1 GB space, just as the first one. Is there a way to write only the changed sectors according to UDF VAT documentation?
Need any method or API that works for Windows.